# Dynamic choose connection entity framework rest

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, rest, odata

I have a very simple entity framework (.edmx) file, and a .svc rest service.

Everything works fine for CRUD operations.

I have many databases thats shares the exactly same schema.

My next step is to let the client pass inn a parameter that could be the connection string or some other value identifying the user so that the service serves data from the correct database.

Now, the only parameter is the uri for the ServiceRoot

I see in the datamodel that I can pass inn a connection string, but how can i do this from the client without making many service files.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using WCF Data Services to expose the edmx file.  I am no expert in this toolset but I suspect the only direct way is to create a service for each database.

This is a great question and it is a scenario that I hope will be addressed in the future WCF HTTP stack.

In the meanwhile, there is some positive news.  I have experimented in the past with creating a large number of service hosts (around 1000) and my experimentation showed that it was quite efficient to start up and did not consume large amounts of RAM.  The key is to create the service hosts in code rather than via the config files.  Obviously, you don't want to be hand writing an XML config file with thousands of service entries in it!

It may not be the ideal solution but I believe it would work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WCF Data Services you should be able to pass the information identifying the data source to use in the HTTP request. Either as a custom option in the URL or as a custom HTTP header (I would probably use the custom header as it's much easier to work with from the client).
Depending on the way you host the service you should be able to access the headers of the request on the server. You can use the ASP.NET way to do this (static variables), or you can hook into the processing pipeline of the WCF Data Services which should allow you to access those headers as well.